# org-habit - Can I arrange for a habit to take place n times during a week, but on indeterminate days?

Tags: org-mode, org-habit

In some habit-tracking apps nowadays, the user can set for the activity to take place on indeterminate days, as long as it's done n times a week *in total*. So for example if I want to go to the gym 4 times a week, I wouldn't care if I went there on certain specific days during the week. Is there a similar functionality in org mode/org-habit? It seems that `"+1d/2d"` style of scheduling is really the closest thing I can get, but that doesn't exactly achieve the same thing as described above.